# How can I rotate my display orientation by 90 degrees?

Tags: windows, resolution, display, portrait, landscape

I want to use my [HP Mini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Mini) as an eBook reader, but I would like to hold it like a book and rotate the screen. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> does not work on this model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[EeeRotate](http://vk.edward.li.googlepages.com/eeerotate)** - A tiny program to **rotate your screen and touchpad** at the same time. Especially designed for EeePC but should work with all computers.

**Ctrl + Alt + Right**: rotate screen and touchpad by 270 degrees

**Ctrl + Alt + Up**: back to normal

*EeeRotate is freeware and portable, no installation required.*

p.s.: this works like a charm with my HP mini, the touchpad rotation is a real blessing.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. I tried irotate, but it didn't rotate the trackpad, which got annoying.

Comment: Where do we get eeerotate in 2023? My first Google hit led me to a site that installs a sketchy "PC App Store" installer. I can rotate the screen and touchpad independently through system settings but I want to do both quickly, and in tandem. That's what eeerotate seems to have been good for.

Answer (score 6):

Try a screen rotation utility, such as [iRotate](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Video-Tweak/iRotate.shtml).

Your video driver must have the required capacity for this (but most now do).

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to install the graphics card control panel, you can generally get these bundled with the drivers from whoever your card/chipset's manufacturer is' website.

Comment: Unfortunately, It's already installed and does not offer this feature.

Comment: oh! How very odd! What sort of card is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intel Graphics you would need to enable hotkeys from the Intel dropdown menu when right-clicking the desktop.